# TSX0108 logic level converter not working

Tags: arduino-uno

Am trying to setup logic level converter with arduino for eps8266 WiFi module. Am using this logic level converter but it’s not working not sure what am doing am not getting any output.

My circuit

```
Red wire : 3.3v power source 
Orange wire : 5v power source 
Blue wire : ground. 
Yellow wire : arduino TX1 on B2
White wire : output on A2
```

[image]

**Multi meter it red wire : 3.3 v showing on display**

[image]

**Multi meter it orange wire : 4.68 v showing on display**

[image]

**Multi meter it yellow wire : 4.36 v showing on display**

[image]

**Multi meter it white wire : no voltage showing on display ??? **

[image]

Update : have set OE pin to enable and swapped red and orange. Still no output for yellow wire

[image]

Comment: power the 5 V side with 5 V and the 3.3 V side with 3.3 V (swap orange and red wre)

Comment: @Juraj i switched orange and red wire  but no output yet , can u check updated image i added

Comment: try with a pin set HIGH

Comment: @Juraj ya TX RX  pins of arduino are always high , i can get voltage when on multi meter when connect it with yellow wire, but in front of no voltage on white wire.

Comment: datasheet of TXB0108: "The A  port is designed to track VCCA. VCCA accepts any supply voltage from1.2 V to 3.6 V. The B port is designed to track VCCB. VCCB accepts any supply voltage from 1.65V to 5.5 V." "The TXB0108 is designed so that the OE input circuit is supplied by VCCA.". did you damage it with 5 V?

Comment: hmmmm seems its burned out , i will buy another one then will try

Answer (score 1):

When the output-enable(OE) input is low, all outputs are placed in the high-impedance (Hi-Z) state.  You must connect the OE pin to logic high to enable the outputs.

Comment: hmmmm no success i have set OE to high but no output for yellow wire yet , can you check updated image i added